# String contains any element of an Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I have a string and an Array

```
NSString* myStr = @" Provide details. Share your research.";
NSArray *array = @[@"share", "your", "dream"];
```

What is the best way (scalable) to check if the string contains any members of the array?

Please note that new elements would be added to the array array

Comment: you say that new elements can be added to the array, but is the string constant or will it also be modified?

Comment: Sad that this question was closed. I find the answers to the other question not very "scaling" since they all take a linear approach - much room for improvement here...

Comment: Can consider it to be a NSMutableArray.

Comment: You are able to post an answer to the original question, @Lasse.